# How to show context help when view is showed in eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created my own tool in my eclipse RCP application. When tool is activated the specific view is opened and when I pressed F1 button I want to show an dynamic help.

I set my context.xml and in my View's `createPartControl` function I have this line:

```
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp(parent, "lineer.udig.tools.yoltool.bufferView.myId");
```

"lineer.udig.tools.yoltool.bufferView" is my view ID and
"myId" is my context-id `<context id="myId">` in context.xml.

When I selected my tool, view is opening and when I click any textBox on this view and press <kbd>F1</kbd> , dynamic help works.

However, I want to show this help anywhere on this view without click textBox or comboBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function createPartControl is taking parameter of "Composite parent"

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
     ..
     ..
}
```

So if we make the composite a private variable `private Composite parent;` then in function

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
     ..
     this.parent = parent;
}
```

And at the end of the class we need to add these two lines to setFocus() function.

```
    public void setFocus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           if(parent != null) // NEW
               parent.setFocus(); // NEW

    }
```

So after these modifications, our dynamic help works automatically when the view is activated.